# X-axis restarts - KendoUI

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

Using this example below, the x-axis series are not starting from the same x value. The x-axis will restart at 0 half way through.

```
function createChart() {
   $("#chart").kendoChart({
   title: {
      text: "Path"
    },
   categoryAxis: {                            
      labels: {                                
          step: 10,
          format: "####"
       },
   },
   valueAxis: {
      reverse: true,
   },
   series: [{
         type: "line",
         field: "y",
         categoryField: "x",
         name: "Path1",
         style: "smooth",
         data: stats,
         markers: {
           visible: false
          }
        }, {
        type: "line",
        field: "y",
        categoryField: "x",
        name: "Path2",
        style: "smooth",
        data: stats2,
        markers: {
        visible: false
         }
    }],
  });
}
```

[image]

http://jsfiddle.net/1sgt4810/30/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution:

Rather than using type `line`, I should have used `scatterLine` based on the following example http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/dataviz/chart/overview#multiple-xy-axes

```
seriesDefaults: { 
        type: "scatterLine"
},
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3yhbyy2g/1/